# XML and DOM getting #text output

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm trying to read a Collada XML file by iterating through a child node list, and every other output reads #text.  What's this about?  My code:

```
public void runTest() {
    File file = new File( "test.dae" );
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    }
    catch( ParserConfigurationException error ) {
        System.out.println( "--ParserConfigurationException: " + error.getMessage() ); return;
    }
    Document document = null;
    try {
        document = builder.parse( file );
    }
    catch( IOException error ) {
        System.out.println( "--IOException: " + error.getMessage() ); return;
    }
    catch( SAXException error ) {
        System.out.println( "--SAXException: " + error.getMessage() ); return;
    }
    Node node = document.getDocumentElement();
    String node_name = node.getNodeName();
    System.out.println( node_name );
    NodeList node_list = node.getChildNodes();
    for( int iterator = 0; iterator < node_list.getLength(); iterator++ ) {
        Node child_node = node_list.item( iterator );
        String child_node_name = child_node.getNodeName();
    System.out.println( "-- " + child_node_name );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"#text" is simply the result of calling the getNodeName() method on a Text node. (As you will see if you look at the API documentation for org.w3c.dom.Node.) If you want the actual text contents of the node, you would use the getNodeValue() method.

And if you weren't expecting there to be any Text nodes, don't forget that even little bits of whitespace, like new-line characters, are treated as text.

Comment: Hmm. I'd expect there to be text in the text nodes. I just didn't expect getNodeName() to do anything other than to, well, get the node name. Here it seems like it moonlights as getNodeType() or whatever. Anyway, I'm not going to question why, there probably is a good reason. As of now I just have to add code like if( node_name == "#text" ) continue; to get what I want.

Comment: For future reference, there is a better way to go about getting just the elements. Check out the `getElementsByTagName` method of the `Element` interface. You can use `getElementsByTagName("*")` to get just the element children of a given element. It requires some casting to `Element` if you are looking through a NodeList, but it's worth it.